# Logging system state

Tags: performance, monitoring, logging

My friend's laptop has a tendency to turn itself off every once in a while. I don't have access to it, but I would like to install a utility that constantly monitors its state and logs it somewhere, so I can take a look at the traces just before it shut down. (Something similar to SAR logs for Linux)

Do you have a recommendation for such utility?

Comment: You didn't specify the OS. From your question it is not clear if the laptop is running Linux or not.

Comment: what system-windows is event veiwer detailed enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should log all you require- [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/goto/EventLogs_Download).